# Which one can be a square number?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Which one can be a square number?

$1)\overline{ab\cdots18}$

$2)\overline{ab\cdots42}$

$3)\overline{ab\cdots46}$

$4)\overline{ab\cdots89}$

To solve this question I considered $17^2=289$ and last two digits of this perfect square is $89$ therefor I conclude the answer is $\overline{ab\cdots89}$. but I couldn't find a mathematically proof for that (I just tried a number and find out last digits can be $89$) . is there other approach to solve the qustion?

Comment: Consider modulo 4.

Comment: @player3236 in module $4$ first three numbers are $2$ and last one is $1$ I don't know how to connect this with perfect numbers.

Comment: Every perfect square has residue $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. This can be shown easily by cases : $(1)$ $n = 2k$ $(2)$ $n = 2k+1$

Comment: Thank you very much I got it.

Comment: Why the bar notation here ?

Comment: @Peter: the bar notation means that $\overline{ab \dots 18}$ should be interpreted as a (base 10) number, not a multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. If you find the last two digits of every square from $0$ to $50$, you will find this pattern: $$00, 01, 04, 09, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 00, 21, 44, 69, 96, 25, 56, 89, 24, 61, 00, 41, 84, 29, 76, 25, 76, 29, 84, 41, 00, 61, 24, 89, 56, 25, 96, 69, 44, 21, 00, 81, 64, 49, 36, 25, 16, 09, 04, 01, 00$$

This pattern of last two digits repeats every $50$ numbers. $89$ is your only two digits that appears in this set, so $89$ is the answer.

Comment: Actually, just the last digit is sufficient.  Compute 6 one-digit squares instead of 51 two-digit squares.

Comment: @B. Goddard, that's true for 1) and 2), but there are square numbers that end in $6$. Or am I not understanding what you're saying?

Comment: No, I missed the 6.  But mod 4 actually does the job.